# R: find index of (best/incompletely) matching elements in two lists

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, purrr

I have two lists of character vectors called *three_letters* and *four_letters* defined as:

```
three_letters <- replicate(sample(letters, size = 3), n = 100, simplify = FALSE)

four_letters <- sample(three_letters, replace = FALSE, size = 100) %>%
  map(.f = ~ c(., sample(LETTERS, 1)))
```

where each element in the *three_letters* list has a corresponding element in the *four_letters* list sharing all but one "subelement" letter.

I would like to produce a 1D vector of the INDEX of the element in list *four_letters* that matches (3 out of 4, or generalized n out of m if possible) each element in list *three_letters*.

I'm likely overthinking this but here's the tedious and very non-generalizable solution I've come up with:

```
# first define helper function:
count_unique_list <- function(l1_element, l2_element){
  length(unique(unlist(append(l1_element,l2_element))))
}

# use nested map() functions

four_letter_indices <-
# for every element in three_letters:
  map(three_letters, .f = function(x){
    # for every element in four_letters:
    map(four_letters, .f = function(y){
      # is the length of unique union equal to 4?
      count_unique_list(x,y) == 4
    }) %>%
      # return index of TRUE
      detect_index(.f = isTRUE)
  }) %>%
  unlist()

# to check success visually I used cbind on arrayified lists:
cbind(matrix(unlist(three_letters), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE),
      matrix(unlist(four_letters[four_letter_indices]), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE))
```

If possible, I would especially like a Hadley-Wickham-styled "tidy" solution to this as those make the most sense to me and tend to be more deployable in my current data analysis pipelines.

Cheers

Comment: The _count_unique_list()_ approach might seem a bit weird. Alternatively, one can also use the following helper function: `count_intersection_list <- function(l1_element, l2_element){
  length(intersect(unlist(l1_element),unlist(l2_element)))
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
three_letters %>%
  map(~{a = .x;which(map_lgl(four_letters,~all(a %in% .x)))})
```

We need to reassign the outer `.x` to a new variable because inside the nested `map` `.x` will be reassigned to the second level.

`{...}` just allows you to evaluate multiple expressions and only return the last. The expressions are separated by `;` or a new line.

In tidyevaluation, `~` denotes the lambda function expression

```
function(...)
```

Or more precisely, a formula created with `~` is converted to a function. The first argument of `...` is asigned to `.`, `.x` and `..1`. See [`help(purrr::map)`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) for more.

Comment: Clever! Would you call the contents of the "{}" in the outer map() a formula or function? And you're using the semicolon in order to write a multi-line formula/function anonymously? This is very strange but makes perfect sense. Do you know of a resource that provides more examples of this?

Comment: `{...}` just allows you to evaluate multiple expressions and only return the last. The expressions are separated by `;` or a new line. In tidyevaluation, `~` just denotes the lambda function expression (ie `function(...)`).